# What triggers ENIs to be created for AWS Lambdas accessing VPC resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have multiple lambdas deployed with access to our VPC using the `VpcConfig` setting.

I understand that AWS Lambda normally creates lambdas on demand, but if you have them connecting to your VPC then AWS will (at some point) create an ENI on one of the subnets specified in the `VpcConfig` and attach the lambda container to allow it access to your VPC.

But what actually triggers the ENI to be created and attached? I've noticed that there is not a 1-to-1 mapping between lambdas and ENIs, nor between ENIs and subnets. Also what decides which subnet the ENI attaches to?

If I run a test lambda (to `ping localhost`) manually, configured for our VPC, it never creates an ENI. So I'm guessing this is because it is not trying to access anything on the network.

Comment: "it never creates an ENI" should be because there already is one available.  Verify that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This requires an understanding of Lambda containers and container reuse. When a Lambda function is first invoked a Lambda container is created and the Lambda function is deployed into the container. That container will be assigned an ENI if you have the function configured with VPC settings. Then the next time you invoke the function, if the container still exists with the function deployed, and isn't currently in use by another invocation, it will re-use that container (so no need to create a new ENI). If the container is busy handling another invocation then a second container will be deployed with a new ENI to handle the pending invocation. When a container is idle for a period of time then the Lambda service will automatically delete the container and the attached ENI.

> Also what decides which subnet the ENI attaches to?

When you configured the Lambda function for VPC access you were required to list one or more subnets in the VPC that it would be deployed to. I don't believe the actual algorithm has been published by Amazon but it appears to use a round-robin algorithm to spread container creation out between the configured subnets. For practical purposes you could consider it to "randomly" pick a subnet every time it creates a new Lambda container. I assume it will also check that there are available IP addresses in the subnet, or fail over to another subnet if it has issues obtaining an IP for the new ENI in a given subnet, but again, I'm not aware of that being documented anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. This answer corresponds with my experiments. But I'm now wondering if Security Group has any effect on ENI reuse - or is that applied to the lambda itself rather than the ENI?

Comment: All instances of a specific Lambda function will have the same Security Group. I fail to see how that would affect the ENI reuse at all, since it wouldn't be changing.

Comment: In a normal deployment scenario it wouldn't but the AWS console/API lets you change these things post-deployment. Trying to work out if changing the SG during diagnostics may have altered ENI creation

Comment: You can change security groups assigned to an ENI on the fly. I'm not sure if making the change in the Lambda console would do it on the fly, or if any change to the Lambda configuration would just deploy your Lambda function in a new container. Not sure why it should really matter, in general you shouldn't expect the Lambda ENIs to be long-lived.