# Lambda function in multiple subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

If a Lambda function is deployed in multiple subnets, how does it decide which subnet to run in when it is invoked? Is it just random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think AWS makes this aspect of lambda invoke behavior public, but this answer aligns with my experience - the lambda will be invoked in a random subnet from the defined subnet_ids:

[What triggers ENIs to be created for AWS Lambdas accessing VPC resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214781/what-triggers-enis-to-be-created-for-aws-lambdas-accessing-vpc-resources)

Answer (score 0):

I just had issue with that and I have contacted AWS support to get help. They have confirmed that **[lambda will be always invoked in a random subnet!](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function)** - *“when an Amazon VPC-connected Lambda function makes requests, it randomly selects an associated subnet. If the function uses a misconfigured subnet, then you get an error.”*. So, when your lambda sometimes works and sometimes don't, it's good idea to check you VPC configuration. Especially check if your subnets connected to lambda have access to all used resources inside lambda.